# OpenCV-Python: Draw Parabolical Line

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to draw a curved line, but I just can't figure out how to do that.

I've got 3 coordinates to work with - [line_start_x, line_start_y], [clicked_x, clicked_y], and [line_end_x, line_end_y] and my code looks like this:

```
pts = np.array(
        [
            [line_start_x, line_start_y],
            [clicked_x, clicked_y],
            [line_end_x, line_end_y],
        ], np.int32)
image = cv2.polylines(image, [pts], True, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow(window_name, image)
```

However, the above code outputs a triangle and not a parabolical line, as I need.

I'd appreciate any help with that matter!

Comment: Why would you expect that a function called "polylines" with 3 points as input would draw anything different from a triangle?

Comment: 2 points of the curve will be always fixed in half_x of the rectangle?

Comment: @UlisesBussi - Yes.

Comment: @Miki - I am just getting into OpenCV, and I don't know any better. I tried searching online but couldn't find any viable solution. Can you point me to the right direction?

Comment: @Johnny so the other point will not be necesarily your vertix. you can calculate the vertix and find amplitude to pass for de clicked point, i'm doing the maths, gime some minutes

Comment: you need bezier or spline curves. if you have to do that yourself, you need to calculate points along the curve, and then draw straight lines between those points.

Answer (score 1):

assuming I understand the problem, 2 points will be ever fixed (line_start,line_end). when you have 3 points an a 2nd grade polinomial you there's only onse solution. you can calculate the expresion using numpy and then draw it evaluating this is a toy example with fixed image an point (change it's coords and try diferent solutions). I didn't put any condition on clicked_point so it could be out of the rect.

1. create image, rectangle and put bias points

   ```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

    width,height = 900,600
    img = np.zeros((height,width,3), np.uint8)
    white_rect = np.array([[100, 100],
                           [width-100, 100],
                           [width-100, height-100],
                           [100, height-100],
                           [100, 100] ], np.int32)

    img = cv2.polylines(img, [white_rect], True, (255,255,255), 3)

    line_start_x = int(white_rect[0:2,0].mean())
    line_start_y = int(white_rect[0:2,1].mean())
    line_end_x   = int(white_rect[2:4,0].mean())
    line_end_y   = int(white_rect[2:4,1].mean())
    clicked_x    = 555
    clicked_y    = 192

    img =cv2.circle(img, (clicked_x, clicked_y), 5, (0,0,255), -1)
    img =cv2.circle(img, (line_start_x, line_start_y), 5, (0,0,255), -1)
    img =cv2.circle(img, (line_end_x, line_end_y), 5, (0,0,255), -1)



    cv2.imshow('fr', img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
   ```
2. Then create point array 'pts' fit parabola and evaluate with numpy.

   ```
    pts = np.array([ [line_start_x, line_start_y],
                     [clicked_x, clicked_y],
                     [line_end_x, line_end_y] ], np.int32)

    #side parabola coeffs

    coeffs = np.polyfit(pts[:,1], pts[:,0], 2)
    poly = np.poly1d(coeffs)

    yarr = np.arange(line_start_y, line_end_y)
    xarr = poly(yarr)
   ```
3. create parab points as int to draw with polylines (might be other choices but i'm gonna use this for simplicity).

   ```
    parab_pts = np.array([xarr, yarr],dtype=np.int32).T
    cv2.polylines(img, [parab_pts], False, (255,0,0), 3)

    cv2.imshow('fr', img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
   ```

## The output !!!

[image: the Output!]

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick!
I've got a follow-up question - say the medial line is still present in the image after drawing the parabola - how can I get all the pixels that are in the area between it and the parabola (not including the edges)?

Comment: jmm As I see it you have 2 posible options (that I can recall now). Put together teh medial line and the parabola as one set of data (polyline-like) then you can create a mask image in opencv and count pixels ( fillpoly to make a filled figure). or use shapely to calc area... Try it yourself, if doesn't work. Edit the question  adding this part or create another one (please pass link)